# Not able to run Rails in Mac Apple Chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails installed in my Macbook. But is not getting detected.
Check following commands.

```bash
~/W/exp $ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [arm64-darwin22]
~/W/exp $ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
~/W/exp $ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

What should be done to fix it?

Comment: I very frequently direct people to https://dontusesystemruby.com/ when they are using system Ruby. You are using system Ruby. Don't do that.

Comment: Agree with the above. Don't use the system Ruby and gems. Use something like rbenv or RVM to install Ruby on a per-project basis.